# @RequestBody Object does not deserialize automatically

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, data-binding, jackson

I use Spring-boot 2.0.1 with WebFlux as Rest server.

In me RestController I would like to automatically deserialize an object (Product). But I get a Jackson error as if ParameterNamesModule was not registered.

> Caused by:
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot
>   construct instance of `com.truc.Product` (no Creators, like default
>   construct, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate-
>   or property-based Creator)  at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException.from(InvalidDefinitionException.java:67)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportBadDefinition(DeserializationContext.java:1451)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1027)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializerBase.deserializeFromObjectUsingNonDefault(BeanDeserializerBase.java:1290)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:326)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:159)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader._bind(ObjectReader.java:1574)
>     at
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectReader.readValue(ObjectReader.java:965)
>     at
>   org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Decoder.lambda$decodeInternal$0(AbstractJackson2Decoder.java:113)
>     ... 287 common frames omitted

I have `jackson-module-parameter-names` in my pom

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
     <artifactId>jackson-module-parameter-names</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

And this the route in RestController

```
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<Entity<Product>> postProduct(@RequestBody Product product) {
    return productService.insert(product);
}
```

If I try to deserialize manually it works :

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
...
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Mono<Entity<Product>> postProduct(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
    return exchange.getRequest().getBody()
            .last().flatMap(buffer -> {
        try {
            Product product = objectMapper.readValue(buffer.asInputStream(), Product.class);
            return productService.insert(product);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    });
}
```

This is my Product.class

```
package com.truc;

import java.time.LocalDate; import java.util.Optional;

public final class Product {
    public static final String PREFIX = "PT";

    public final String description;
    public final String shortDescription;
    public final String sku;
    public final float weight;
    public final LocalDate newSince;
    public final LocalDate newUntil;
    public final Status status;
    public final Visibility visibility;
    public final String metaKeywords;

    public Product(String description, String shortDescription, String sku, Float weight,
                   LocalDate newSince, LocalDate newUntil, Status status, Visibility visibility, String metaKeywords) {
        this.description = description;
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
        this.sku = sku;
        this.weight = Optional.ofNullable(weight).orElse(0f);
        this.newSince = newSince;
        this.newUntil = newUntil;
        this.status = status;
        this.visibility = visibility;
        this.metaKeywords = metaKeywords;
    }

    public enum Status {
        ACTIVE, INACTIVE
    }

    public enum Visibility {
        FULL, CATALOG, SEARCH, NONE
    } 
}
```

If I understand `@JsonCreator` is not required after `jackson-databind` 2.9, I use jackson 2.9.5

If I add `@JsonCreator` I get a new error `415 Unsupported Content-Type 'application/json'` ...

I don't understand where I'm wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: looks like a no default constructor error. can you also share the product class? Basically you should either have a default constructor or a constructor with no input or tell the jackson how to construct the entity with @JsonCreator  entity

Comment: Sure, I complete the question with Product code.

For `@JsonCreator` If I add it I get a new error 415 Unsupported Content-Type 'application/json'

thanks for your response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43195987/configured-objectmapper-not-used-in-spring-boot-webflux#comment73700455_43241547) `@EnableWebFlux` deactivate all the webflux auto-configuration. And I use it in Configuration class without extend the class with `WebFluxConfigurer`.

When I remove `@EnableWebFlux` it work again, the ObjectMapper is configured as expected.

So it's ok
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to add **default constructor** in your RequestBody class which is ProductClass then it will work